# Accessing Djnago generic DetialView directly from CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I'm trying to acomplish the following functionality: the user enters required information in the form created using generic CreateView, in this case it is length and width. After the form is submitted the app performs simple calculations and returns the result along with submitted data. 
I tried to follow this example: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views

My models:

```
from django.db import models


class Building(models.Model):

length = models.IntegerField(default=1)
width = models.IntegerField(default=1)
area = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.area = self.length * self.width
   super().save(*args, **kwargs)re
```

views:

```
class BuildingDetailView(DetailView):
model = Building
context_object_name = 'building'

class BuildingCreateView(CreateView):
model = Building
form_class = BuildingForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('building-detail')

class BuildingListView(ListView):
model = Building

class BuildingUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Building
form_class = BuildingForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('building_detail')
```

urls:

```
path('', views.indexView, name='index'),
path('add_temp/', views.BuildingCreateView.as_view(), name='building_add'),
path('buildings/', views.BuildingListView.as_view(), name='building_changelist'),
path('building/<int:pk>/', views.BuildingDetailView.as_view(), name='building-detail'),
```

html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Title: </h1>

{% for object in object_list %}

<p><strong>Length:</strong> {{ object.length }}</p>
<p><strong>Width:</strong> {{ object.width }}</p>
<p><strong>Area:</strong> {{ object.area }}</p>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This setup is giving me the following error. I assume the problem is in my template:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  126.         return super().form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  57.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_success_url
  112.         if self.success_url:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __wrapper__
  151.                 res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  673.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /hr/add_temp/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'building-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hr\\/building\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`get_success_url(...)`** method,

```
class BuildingCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Building
    form_class = BuildingForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('building-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})


class BuildingUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Building
    form_class = BuildingForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('building-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Answer (score 1):

`reverse_lazy('building-detail')` will not work because "building-detail" requires a parameter "pk". You have 2 options:

Override the `get_success_url` method in your views

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('building-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Or add a `get_absolute_url` method to your `Building` model, this will be used by all the update/create views by default and doesn't require adding `success_url` or `get_success_url` to your views

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('building-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```